# Is there a way to rename all methods and properties to the correct case?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to enforce camel case across an entire project. I've tried ReSharper's Code Cleanup feature but it doesn't support renaming.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is this something that StyleCop can do?

Thanks

Comment: No StyleCop can just check this rule and warn you about violation.

Comment: ReSharper has a rename function. Depends on which shortcut you've set, try control r, r. Takes time to rename everything but it changes all occurences at once.

Comment: Yeah that is what I currently use but it still only does one method at a time. I ended up just going through the solution and doing it by hand.